# I want to display a 'No data available' message in AmCharts 3

Tags: javascript, amcharts, no-data

[image]

I want to display a 'No data available' message in AmCharts 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
         if (FilteredData.length === 0) {
             cdChart.allLabels = [{
                 "text": '@Html.LocalizedString("NoRecordFound")',
                 "align": "middle",
                 "size": 12,
                 "y": "50%",
                 "x": "50%"
             }];
         }
```

[image]